# Unique solution for a specific system of polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $x^{(1)}, \dots, x^{(N)} \in \mathbb R^n$ be given. Suppose all we know about the $x^{(i)}$ are the values $c_1, \dots, c_N$ as given below
\begin{align*}
&c_1 := \sum_{i=1}^N \langle v^{(j)}, x^{(i)} \rangle \;\, = \sum_{|\alpha|=1} v^{(j)}_\alpha  \left(  \sum_{i=1}^N (x^{(i)})^{\alpha} \right), \\
&c_2:=\sum_{i=1}^N \langle v^{(j)}, x^{(i)} \rangle^2 = \sum_{|\alpha|=2} v^{(j)}_\alpha  \left( \sum_{i=1}^N (x^{(i)})^{\alpha} \right), \\
& \hspace{2.9cm}\vdots \\
&c_N:=\sum_{i=1}^N \langle v^{(j)}, x^{(i)} \rangle^N = \sum_{|\alpha|=Nst} v^{(j)}_\alpha  \left( \sum_{i=1}^N (x^{(i)})^{\alpha} \right),
\end{align*}
for certain vectors $v^{(1)}, \dots, v^{(M)} \in \mathbb R^n$.

What are conditions on these vectors so that the equations for $j = 1, \dots, M$
can be solved uniquely for the terms $\sum_{i=1}^N (x^{(i)})^{\alpha}$ for all $1 \le |\alpha| \le N$?

Of course, an obvious solution is the requirement that for an arbitrary fixed order $p=|\alpha|$, the corresponding family of $M$ vectors $w_{p}^{(1)}, \dots, w_{p}^{(M)}$ given by $w_{p}^{(j)}:=(v_{\alpha}^{(j)})_{|\alpha|=p}$ spans the corresponding ambient space.

But I have strong belief, that this condition is overly conservative and in fact not necessary! Any comments and hints are very welcome. Thank you!